# magento email template format for contact page comment text area field

Tags: magento-1.7, email-templates

In my webshop I have contact form and it is submitted successfully, but Comment text area field content show in one line. Suppose customer write like this(with line break) -

Hello, I would like to get a price for the product XY.

I am using this code

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Please tell me what i do ?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your are using a html reader to view the mail and the e-mail which is send is just plain-text.

Therefore it is all in one line.

You could go and edit: app/locale/en_US(or your locale)/email/contact_form.phtml and add some html code to it.

```
<!--@subject Contact Form@-->
<!--@vars
{"var data.name":"Sender Name",
"var data.email":"Sender Email",
"var data.telephone":"Sender Telephone",
"var data.comment":"Comment"}
@-->
<body>
Name: {{var data.name}}<br />
E-mail: {{var data.email}}<br />
Telephone: {{var data.telephone}}<br />
<br />
Comment: {{var data.comment}}<br />
</body>
```

Only the last line will be in one line.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the comment into the `nl2br` function. This should convert it and then display it correctly.

```
{{var data.comment:escape|nl2br}}
```

Comment: Was looking for something like this, unfortunately does not work for me in M2 html email template, it doesn't echo the variable if I do this

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Comment: {{var data.comment|nl2br}}
```